# Calculate and update power consumption between current and last row base on timestamps

Tags: mysql

Unfortunately my SQL skills are very basic. I hope someone can help me. I would like to calculate the power consumption (counter reading) in Wh (Watt/h) base on the time difference between two rows of the same device.

I have a table (mysql) with deviceID, Date, CounterReading (Wh) and currently empty, ActivePower (Watt) and some other columns. In the table "device_data" approx. each minute the devices insert a new row with the current power usage (field activePower). timestamp is in field date. On an hourly bases I would like to run a script that calculates the counter reading (Wh) and updates each row. The calculated Wh need to be added to the last value save in the table.

I know the formula, but I have no skills to write a proper sql query that calculates counter reading and updates the table.

> Formula: Wh = 'timediff in sec' * activePower / 3600
>   Example: 55s * 9.1601 / 3600 = 0.139945972 Wh (4 digits after . should be enough).

The calculated Wh must be added to the last entry of the counterReading. Currently the CounterReading field is 'NULL' and I would like to start with 0 Wh and sum it up until today.

Sometimes ActivePower can also be 0 (= no power usage of the device behind the power plug). In this case the CounterReading value must be the same as the last entry.

Below is an example of my table "device_data" with two devices.

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------+--------+
|   DeviceId   |        DATE         | Counter | Active |
|              |                     | Reading | POWER  |
+--------------+---------------------+---------+--------+
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:34:02 | NULL    | 9.1150 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:35:01 | NULL    | 9.2129 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:36:01 | NULL    | 9.1962 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:37:01 | NULL    | 9.1741 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:38:02 | NULL    | 9.1123 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:39:02 | NULL    | 9.1256 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:40:01 | NULL    | 9.2432 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:41:02 | NULL    | 9.1924 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:42:02 | NULL    | 9.2486 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:43:01 | NULL    | 9.2040 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:44:01 | NULL    | 9.0565 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:45:01 | NULL    | 9.1879 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:46:01 | NULL    | 9.2045 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:47:02 | NULL    | 9.1986 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 2019-06-28 17:48:04 | NULL    | 9.1601 |
+--------------+---------------------+---------+--------+
```

Here an example of the final result I would like to have:

```
+--------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
|   DeviceId   |       DATE        | CounterReading | ActivePower |
+--------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:48:04 |         0.0000 |      9.1601 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:47:02 |         0.1559 |      9.1986 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:46:01 |         0.3093 |      9.2045 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:45:01 |         0.4599 |      9.1879 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:44:01 |         0.6083 |      9.0565 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:43:01 |         0.7591 |       9.204 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:42:02 |         0.9081 |      9.2486 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:41:02 |         1.0588 |      9.1924 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:40:01 |         1.2128 |      9.2432 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:39:02 |         1.3599 |      9.1256 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:38:02 |         1.5092 |      9.1123 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:37:01 |         1.6621 |      9.1741 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:36:01 |         1.8128 |      9.1962 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:35:01 |         1.9638 |      9.2129 |
| B4E62DE92CE9 | 28.06.19 17:34:02 |         2.1107 |       9.115 |
+--------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Would be great if someone could help me.

Kind regards
Patrik

Comment: Hi maraguma - your question is really hard to read. Can you reformat the data using `code` blocks to allow columns to line up, and remove irrelevant columns? It's hard to tell, but we probably don't need so many rows. And maybe for the sake of this exercise just use 1,2,3,4... for the ids.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB version 10.3.15

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`LAG`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lag/) window function to retrieve the previous row.

The following SQL calculates the time difference between two rows:

```
SELECT date - LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) FROM device_data;
```

With this, you should be able to create an SQL statement that does what you need it to do.

**Edit:**

To sum up the values, you could use a CTE:

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT date, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) - LAG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC)) * activepower / 3600 AS Wh FROM device_data
) SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t.Wh) OVER (ORDER BY t.date), 0) FROM t;
```

Comment: I tried what you proposed but timeDiff seems to be wrong. Couldn't add proper code example to comment and added new answer.

Comment: I made some progress but was not able to SUM up the counterReading

Answer (score 0):

I'm now able to calculate the watt/h as I had to first convert the date to a UNIX_TIMESTAMP. I'm struggling now in the SQL to SUM up the counterReading is always: `last value of counterRading + Wh`.

Here the SQL that I have so far:

```
SELECT date,
       deviceID,
       activePower,
       counterReading,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) - LAG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC)) * activePower / 3600 AS Wh
    FROM device_data
    WHERE deviceID = 'B4E62DE92E05';
```

I tried something like

```
SELECT ...
    counterReading + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) - LAG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC)) * activePower / 3600 AS Wh
    FROM ...
```

but that didn't work at all. This is the result I'm getting.

```
+---------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| date                | deviceID     | activePower | counterReading | Wh         |
+---------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| 2019-06-28 15:00:02 | B4E62DE92E05 |     80.2636 |           NULL |       NULL |
| 2019-06-28 15:01:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     79.6895 |           NULL | 1.30602236 |
| 2019-06-28 15:02:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     78.8532 |           NULL | 1.31422000 |
| 2019-06-28 15:03:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     78.1088 |           NULL | 1.30181333 |
| 2019-06-28 15:04:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     77.5467 |           NULL | 1.29244500 |
| 2019-06-28 15:05:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     76.2649 |           NULL | 1.27108167 |
| 2019-06-28 15:06:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     76.3540 |           NULL | 1.27256667 |
| 2019-06-28 15:07:01 | B4E62DE92E05 |     74.6706 |           NULL | 1.24451000 |
+---------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: I think you could use a CTE to sum up the values if that's what you want to do. I've updated my answer with the SQL I used to gather up the values.